# Error running Metricbeat.exe commands in powershell

Tags: powershell, elastic-stack, elk, metricbeat

I am trying to install Metricbeat on a Windows 10 machine so we can start monitoring it. When I open Powershell and run the following commands:

PS > .\metricbeat.exe modules list

I get the error

[image: powershellerror]

I copied that command as is from the Metricbeat documentation. I have seen videos on youtube of people running similar commands successfully. Please, why am I getting that error and what can I do to get my metricbeat.exe powershell commands to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're copying the command **TOO** literally.

you've entered in the prompt `PS > .\metricbeat.exe modules list`

where you should have entered `.\metricbeat.exe modules list`

the latter executes `modules list` action against an application named `"metricbeat.exe"` located in `.\` which indicates the current directory.

the former executes a redirection `>` of the output of an application named `PS` or `get-process` with input of `.\metricbeat.exe modules` and an argument of `list`.

wherever you copied this command from intended `"PS >"` to represent the beginning of the prompt and you don't need to include it.

Just like the error says...   :P